# Minimum number steps to reach goal in chess - knight traversal with BFS

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph-algorithm, game-theory

Code given below works for chess of size less than 13 efficiently, but after that it takes too much time and runs forever.
I want to reduce time to reach till end node.
Also this code finds minimum path from starti,startj to endi,endj where starti and startj takes value from 1 to n-1.

Here is the problem that I am trying to solve:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/knightl-on-chessboard/problem

**Program:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;<br>
import java.util.Scanner;

class Node {

    int x,y,dist;

    Node(int x, int y, int dist) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dist = dist;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "x: "+ x +" y: "+y +" dist: "+dist;
    }
}

class Solution {

    public static boolean checkBound(int x, int y, int n) {

        if(x >0 && y>0 && x<=n && y<=n)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void printAnswer(int answer[][], int n) {
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++) {
                System.out.print(answer[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static int findMinimumStep(int n, int[] start, int[] end, int a, int b) {

        LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList();
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[n+1][n+1];
        queue.add(new Node(start[0],start[1],0));       
        int x,y;

        int[] dx = new int[] {a, -a, a, -a, b, -b, b, -b};
        int[] dy = new int[] {b, b, -b, -b, a, a, -a, -a};


        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node z = queue.removeFirst();
            visited[z.x][z.y] = true;

            if(z.x == end[0] && z.y == end[1])
                return z.dist;

            for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
            {
                x = z.x + dx[i];
                y = z.y + dy[i];            
                if(checkBound(x,y,n) && !visited[x][y])
                    queue.add(new Node(x,y,z.dist+1));
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int start[] = new int[] {1,1};
        int goal[] = new int[] {n,n};
        int answer[][] = new int[n-1][n-1];

        for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            for(int j=i; j<n; j++) {
                int result = findMinimumStep(n, start, goal, i, j);
                answer[i-1][j-1] = result;
                answer[j-1][i-1] = result;
            }
        }
        printAnswer(answer,n);

    }
}
```

Comment: Better for Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `visited` too late and the same cells are added multiple times to the queue, then you pop them from the queue without checking their visited state that makes things even worse. This leads to the fast growth of the queue.

You need to set `visited` right after you add the `Node` to the queue:

```
if(checkBound(x,y,n) && !visited[x][y]) {
    queue.add(new Node(x,y,z.dist+1)); 
    visited[x][y] = true;   
}
```

Comment: yeah this worked, previously I modified z.x and z.y instead of x and y. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Even if you optimize your code, you will not reduce the complexity of the algorithm.

I think you need to think about how to reduce the search space. Or search it in a clever order.

I would go for a [A*-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: As graph is unweighted, I think BFS should do the job more efficiently.

Comment: @swapnil: BFS is just a special case of A*-search.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective solution in your problem is [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Treat the squares as nodes and draw edges towards the other squares/nodes that the knight can visit. Then run the algorithm for this graph. It performs in logarithmic time so it scales pretty good for big problems.

A* search suggest by MrSmith, is a heuristic so I would not suggest it for this kind of problem.

Dijkstra is an important algorithm and implementing it will help you solve many similar problems in the future, for example you can also solve [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=81) problem with the same logic.

Comment: The graph is unweighted and there is no need to use Dijkstra or A* algorithms. BFS is good enough for this problem. He simply made a mistake in the implementation.

Comment: Even I agree for an unweighted graph BFS is good. could you let me know more about the mistake that I have made?

Comment: I think Dale is right, BFS will work better here because the edges are always 1. I was just overeager in using Dijkstra cause it is a more generic solution for dynamic programming problems (as the one that I quoted).